# for loop through dict to find max

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, max

There are many examples available that show how to find a max value in a dict.  I was curious though why the maximum key / value cannot found in this way.

```
from random import randint

# Create dict with random keys and values.
d = {randint(1, 99): randint(1, 99) for i, j in enumerate(range(20))}

# Loop through dict to find max value
maxi = 0
for key in d:
    if d[key] > maxi:
        maxi = key

print(d, d[maxi])
```

Visually checking d, it can be seen that d[maxi] is not the max value.

Comment: You can use the `max()` function if you specify a `key` parameter. For example: `max(d, lambda x: d[x])`

Comment: And you shouldn't use 0 as the original max unless you're always going to have positive numbers in the dict.

Comment: @Matt No need for the ugly lambda there.  Use `max(d, key=d.get)`

Comment: @wim Oh yeah, I always forget about that one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if d[key] > maxi` is comparing the current *value* with the maximum *key*. The simplest change would be to write `if d[key] > d[maxi]`. (You could also keep the maximum value as its own variable).

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> d = {"a": 5, "b": 99, "c": 3}
>>> max(d, key=d.get)
'b'
```

Comment: better is `max(d, key=d.get)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that the first time you find a value bigger than 0 you store the **key** instead of the value. Then you compare the next **value** with the last **key** you stored.

In the end you store a number that is not what you want (I don't know if there is even a logic for the number that end up in `maxi` - I guess is just another random number).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to this would be to get **key, value** using dictionary **items()** function and compare the values to find the max.

```
max_key = None
max_val = None

for key, val in your_dict.items():

    if max_val is None or val > max_val:
        max_val = val
        max_key = key


print(max_key, max_val)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key, value in your_dict.items():
   x=max(your_dict,key=your_dict.get)
print("key with the maxi value:",x)
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but the loop here is pointless, since the `x=max...` line does not depend on `key` or `value`, and this is effectively the same solution as [robert king's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14887946/3216427) posted nine years ago. When you add an answer to an old question with several answers, please make sure you are contributing an improvement on existing answers, or a new approach, or a better explanation.